# Data put() to python multiprocessing queue not available for get() until hours later?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing

In my setup, I have several worker processes (one for each cpu core) using put() to add results to a queue. The main process then uses get() to fetch the results and handles logging and disk i/o.

The weird thing is that the queue will show up as empty after something like 5k get() calls, when there have been 500k put() calls. Then (possibly when the put() calls are all finished), the missing data shows up all at once and is available for get(). What could be causing this?

Imports:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
import time
import traceback
import msgpack

# Custom modules
import logbook
import network
```

My worker function (flows is an iterator):

```
def run_min_cut(edges_from, nodes, done_q, return_q, error_q):
    flows = network.min_cut.dinic_unit_pairwise(edges_from, nodes)
    try:
        for flow in flows:
            return_q.put(flow)
    except:
        error_q.put(sys.exc_info())
        return
    done_q.put(1)
```

The loop that writes the results to disk:

```
exp_name = "18_find_min_cut"
edges_file = "archive/17_create_coeditor/2016-11-05 16:42:01 8850183/%d-coeditor.mp"
out_file = "flows.csv"
num_proc = 11
log_period=30

exp = logbook.Experiment(exp_name)
log = exp.get_logger()

log.info("Loading network edges")
all_nodes = set()
edge_count = 0
edges_from = {}
with open(edges_file % 23, "rb") as f:
    unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(f)
    for o in unpacker:
        edge_count += len(o[1])
        edges_from[o[0][0]] = o[1]
        all_nodes.add(o[0][0])
        all_nodes |= set(o[1])
all_nodes = list(all_nodes)
log.info("  Loaded %d nodes and %d edges" % (len(all_nodes), edge_count))

log.info("Starting %d processes" % num_proc)
step = 1 + len(all_nodes) / num_proc
pair_count = len(all_nodes) * (len(all_nodes) - 1)
return_q = Queue()
done_q = Queue()
error_q = Queue()
workers = []
log.info("  Sending %d nodes to each worker" % step)
for i in range(num_proc):
    chunk = all_nodes[(i*step):((i+1)*step)]
    args = (edges_from, chunk, done_q, return_q, error_q)
    p = Process(target=run_min_cut, args=args)
    p.start()
    workers.append(p)

log.info("Waiting for results")
try:
    with open(exp.get_filename(out_file), "wb") as out:
        complete = 0
        proc_complete = 0
        while proc_complete < num_proc and complete < pair_count:
            # Check for errors in worker threads
            if (error_q.qsize() > 0):
                try:
                    e = error_q.get(False)
                    log.error("Caught error from child: %s" % e)
                    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = e
                    traceback.print_tb(exc_tb)
                    [p.terminate() for p in workers]
                    sys.exit()
                except Empty:
                    pass
            # Check for completed threads
            if (done_q.qsize() > 0):
                try:
                    done_q.get(False)
                    proc_complete += 1
                except Empty:
                    pass
            try:
                while 1:
                    flow = return_q.get(False)
                    out.write("%d\n" % flow)
                    complete += 1
            except Empty:
                log.info("  Return queue empty")
            out.flush()
            log.info(
                "  %d of %d pairs and %d of %d cores complete"
                % (complete, pair_count, proc_complete, num_proc))
            time.sleep(log_period)
        log.info(
            "  %d of %d pairs and %d of %d cores complete"
            % (complete, pair_count, proc_complete, num_proc))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    [p.terminate() for p in workers]
```

And an excerpt from the log showing the drastic jump in items read from the queue. With 10/11 cores complete, I know that ~900k items have been put(), but the queue appears empty after ~400k calls to get(), until the missing items all show up at once.

```
2016-11-16 19:31:30,343   0 of 1007012 pairs and 0 of 11 cores complete
2016-11-16 19:32:00,379   Return queue empty
2016-11-16 19:32:00,381   907 of 1007012 pairs and 0 of 11 cores complete
2016-11-16 19:32:30,416   Return queue empty
...
2016-11-16 22:22:44,228   430299 of 1007012 pairs and 10 of 11 cores complete
2016-11-16 22:23:18,158   Return queue empty
2016-11-16 22:23:18,160   1007012 of 1007012 pairs and 11 of 11 cores complete
```

Comment: where are these `.put()` and `.get()` calls coming from? where does `return_q` and `error_q` come from?  could we see the full code to look at your imports to see what modules you are using?

Comment: Adding. Although the rest of the code is just error logging and accounting.

Comment: I have this exact same issue now. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: The problem was an exception within the exception handler of the worker function.  I forget what the exception was, but it happened after the lock was acquired on the queue but before it was released. The process then became a zombie process and the lock was not released until the OS removed it.